# String split with avoid "\n" JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

```
var testString = 'Sr No\tMonth\tMill\tOrigin\tParty\tOrder Date\t"Order Comp.\nDt."\n57\tJan-19\tGINZA\tIND\tSBL\t28.01.2019\t10.02.2019';
var newLine = testString.split('\n');
Oputput of the newLine
[ 'Sr No\tMonth\tMill\tOrigin\tParty\tOrder Date\t"Order Comp.','Dt."','57\tJan-19\tGINZA\tIND\tSBL\t28.01.2019\t10.02.2019' ]
```

Here I want to avoid `\n` for `"Order Comp.\nDt."` when it's in string form

```
[ 'Sr No\tMonth\tMill\tOrigin\tParty\tOrder Date\t"Order Comp.\nDt."','57\tJan-19\tGINZA\tIND\tSBL\t28.01.2019\t10.02.2019' ]
```

Comment: What you're basically asking for is to be able to parse a tab-delimited file. There are likely to be good answers here and elsewhere if you search for that. Let me see if I can find some for you...

Comment: Another similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47876718/splitting-text-file-by-newlines-and-tab-in-javascript

Comment: @Spudley this is not duplicate question. check my output array

Comment: Fair enough; I've reopened it. But it is definitely still asking about parsing tab-delimited values. The `/n` you want to avoid matching is in quotes, which is normal CSV / TSV formatting. Find a good CSV / TSV parser to solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

then instead of spliting the string, why not match the parts that you want to keep?

```js
var testString = 'Sr No\tMonth\tMill\tOrigin\tParty\tOrder Date\t"Order Comp.\nDt."\n57\tJan-19\tGINZA\tIND\tSBL\t28.01.2019\t10.02.2019';

var out = testString.match(/(?:"[^"]*"|[^\n])+/g);

console.log(out);
```